# batch file fails and cannot copy file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, copy

I am currently having issues with my batch file. I am trying to copy the same image several times to fill an SD card. The purpose of this is to write files to fill the SD card so that I can then see if items that have been deleted before these have been copied can be recovered. Automating this process will allow me to complete my project faster and waste less time on copying files.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

REM counts from 0 to count, so 8 = 9 copies
set count=16000

set filename_1=image

set extension=.jpeg

set start_1=

set source=%filename_1%%start_1%%extension%

for /L %%i in (0, 1, %count%) do (
  set /a "number_1=start_1+%%i"
  set destination=%filename_1%!number_1!%extension%
  echo !destination!
  copy %source% !destination!
)

pause
```

This is my current batch file but it fails after 246 copies for some reason. anyone got any explanation why it would only copy that number of times? There is still 1.5GB of free space when it finished running.

Answer (score 0):

try copying all to a folder on your hard-drive first then moving that folder. I ran this file on my hard-drive, and it worked perfectly

Comment: Will try this. Got a different memory stick with me today so will try on that and then test again on the other memory stick. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If sd card is formatted as fat (fat16), you can not put more than 65534 files in a folder, BUT root folder have a limit of 512 files.

If it's formatted as fat32, directories does not have file limit.

BUT in either case, cluster size affects the allocation of files. From microsoft documentation

> FAT16 can waste file storage space in larger drives as the size of the
>   cluster increases. The space allocated for storing a file is based on
>   the size of the cluster allocation granularity, not the file size. A
>   10-KB file stored in a 32-KB cluster wastes 22 KB of disk space.
>
> FAT32 uses space more efficiently than FAT16. FAT32 uses smaller
>   clusters (4 KB for drives up to 8 GB), resulting in 10 to 15 percent
>   more efficient use of disk space relative to large FAT16 drives. FAT32
>   also reduces the resources necessary for the computer to operate.

Check your filesystem

EDIT

Test/adapt this batch file. It will generate a 32kb file in disk and then make copies of it until copy command fails.

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set fillFileName=fillDisk%random%_
    set fillFileExtension=.dat
    set fillFile=%~dp0%fillFileName%%fillFileExtension%

    rem create a file to replicate to fill disk 
    call :createFile "%fillFile%"

    rem Let's fill the disk

    set fileCount=0
:loop
    rem do copy file
    copy "%fillFile%" "%~dp0%fillFileName%%fileCount%%fillFileExtension%" /y >nul 2>nul
    if errorlevel 1 (
        rem file copy failed.
        goto endProcess
    )

    rem copy ok - increment counter
    set /a fileCount=fileCount+1

    rem print indicator on console (show it is working)
    echo.|set /p=.

    rem go to do a new file copy
    goto loop

:endProcess

    rem show final information
    echo.
    echo [ %fileCount% ] files copied
    echo.

    rem disk filled - optional - delete all generated files
    del "%~dp0%fillFileName%*%fillFileExtension%"

    rem clean and exit
    endLocal
    exit /b

:createFile
    rem define a 2k buffer ( 32 * 2^6 )
    set fill=012345678901234567890123456789..
    for /L %%i in (1 1 6) do set fill=!fill!!fill!
    rem correction for crlf at end when output
    set fill=%fill:~0,-2%
    rem output buffer to indicated file (32 kb = 2kb * 16)
    (
        for /L %%i in (1 1 16) do echo %fill%
    ) > "%~1"
    set fill=
    goto :EOF
```

Comment: I will double check this but I formatted the drive and I am pretty sure I chose FAT32 which is what I would normally choose. There are definitely not 65534 files on the disk and not 512 in the root folder so even if it was fat16 surely this should still work? I will reformat but think this should be FAT32 anyway. Just doesnt make much sense. It originally failed after 165 times until I changed the name of the image and made this shorter.

Comment: Updated answer with batch file. Files generated are exactly 32kb to ensure no space lost in cluster alocation (unless your clusters are 64kb, adapt as needed).

Answer (score 0):

Don't copy them to the root directory.  Create a directory in the root called `1` and copy all your files into that one.  It will still overwrite all the sectors if you use files with the same size or multiples of an allocation unit.

Note that filling up the drive storage sectors will not necessarily clear the file tables of all the old file names.